# Reasonable to use a compound literal array as a temporary string buffer?

Tags: c, c-strings, c99

I often wish I had a simple way to construct a string with sprintf/snprintf without the hassle of defining a local array, like so:

```
char str[256];
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), format, ...);
use_string(str);
```

It occurred to me that I could use a compound literal to do this:

```
static inline char* snprintf_assert(char* str, int max_size, const char* format, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, format);
    int count = vsnprintf(str, max_size, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    assert(count >= 0 && count < max_size);
    return str;
}

// Helper sprintf that allocates a buffer local to the block.
// It's using the fact that (char[N]){} will allocate a l-value
// with lifetime tied to the local block.
#define local_sprintf(N, ...) snprintf_assert((char[N]){}, N, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage:

```
use_string(local_sprintf(256, format, ...));
```

I believe this is well defined as the lifetime of the compund literal array will be tied to the enclosing block. Are there any reasons to avoid this?

Comment: Are you aware that the return value of `vsnprintf()` is negative in case of an error? Why don't you use a VLA?

Comment: @thebusybee I've edited the code to take care of negative values. Please explain how VLA helps here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some disadvantages for this technique over simply defining a local array before the call to `snprintf_assert`:

- compound literals are less portable: defining the array with a fixed size `N` (eg: `256`) is portable to C++ and implementations of C that do not support VLAs nor compound literals, defining the array at the beginning of a block being of course fully portable.
- this technique is less efficient: the compound literal `(char[N]){}`, which you could write `(char[N]){0}` for backward portability to C99, defines but also *initializes* the temporary unnamed array, hence you incur the extra `memset()` of `N` bytes to `0`.  This may not be a significant overhead, unless you make `N` large to accommodate potentially large constructed strings.
- less readable: this technique is not a common idiom and the casual reader of your code will ponder about the lifetime of the pointer returned by `local_sprintf`, despite the explicit name.

Conversely, here are some definite advantages:

- versatility: simple function call syntax usable in any expression.
- simplicity: no need to name the temporary char array.
- could be used multiple times via a locally defined pointer with the same scope and lifetime.

  ```
  char *fullname = local_sprintf(256, "%s %s", first, last);
  register_user(fullname);
  output_user(fullname);
  ```

  yet for this use case the advantage over the classic code seems minuscule:

  ```
  char fullname[156];
  snprintf(fullname, sizeof fullname, "%s %s", first, last);
  register_user(fullname);
  output_user(fullname);
  ```

Too bad the array length still needs to be estimated. Of course the actual array size could be computed and passed via an extra call to `snprintf` in the macro, and another one to pass it to snprintf_assert, but multiple evaluation of the macro arguments should be avoided and evaluating `snprintf` 3 times seems inelegant to say the least.

Comment: @ShadowRanger there is a floating "not" missing somewhere in there, because it is certainly NOT portable to "*implementations of C that do not support VLAs nor compound literals*"... (same would apply to strictly-conforming C++) Not like I've never shanked a sentence before ... `:)`

Comment: But, now as edited, it's clear the *fixed size N* was intended. That makes 100% sense to as that would be portable to anything. Chucking, sometimes what is intended isn't always clear... in law, politics or programming.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I edited the answer to clarify the intent.